# Having trouble postponing onOptionsItemSelected action

Tags: java, android

I have a Android app that includes a wallpaper picker.

It loads thumbnails into a gallery widget and when one is selected it displays in a large imageview behind the gallery. All in one Activity

All the wallpapers and thumbs are loading from web by a manifest parser and node. They load just fine.

Problem is that when the menu item to save/apply the wallpaper is pressed before the imageview is loaded has issues. If i wait until the imageview loads it no issue.

I tried getting around this by doing the following.
I had the mImageDrawableSet boolean set to false unless the loading was complete

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mNode.url, mImageView, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted () {
                                mImageDrawableSet = false;
                                mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                mPending.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed (FailReason failReason) {
                                mImageDrawableSet = false;
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image Failed To Load!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete (Bitmap bitmap) {
                                mImageDrawableSet = true;
                                mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                mImageView.setZoomable(true);
                                mPending.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                if (mApplyImageOnDisplay)
                                        applyImage();

                                if (mSaveImageOnDisplay)
                                        exportImage();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingCancelled () {
                        }
                });
```

Then when the exportImage() is called it looks to see if mImageDrawableSet it flase and if it is then it sets mSaveImageOnDisplay  to true. So, when the loading is complete above it will call the exportImage() and process beyond what i posted below.

```
public void exportImage () {
            if (this.mImageDrawableSet == false) {
                    this.mSaveImageOnDisplay = true;
                    return;
            }

            try {
                    final Bitmap bitmap = getImageBitmap();
```

That example from above was from a code where it showed a single imageview in one fragment. I am now using a Activity where all wallpapers are shown in one imageview depending on which thumbnail is selected.
Also I ditched UIL and am not using Picasso and it doesn't a loading started. just loading failed and complete.

So the only way that i have been able to make this work is create a boolean that is set to false on activity start.

Then on option menu item i have this

```
if (ReadyBoolean.getValue()){
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
            applyCrop();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please wait until wallpaper loads", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
```

On the picasso loading complete i set it to true, then back to false after the save function runs.

So, it works but i hate i have to display a message that say please wait until wallpaper loads. I wish it would just work after the imageview loads. I can't seem to figure out how to do it

Comment: How about showing a progress dialogue.?

Comment: Well I have a progress bar for the image view and one in action bar for the button. But the issue is really it crashing when is trying to save an image view that's not loaded yet

Comment: I know more of the code would be helpful but I wanted to try and safe guard it as much as I could